# The Esri map is not working on firefox 43.0.4. any solution?

Tags: firefox, arcgis, esri

I have update my Firefox to 43.0.4 and Esri map stop working. can anyone tell me what is the solution for it?

Comment: They seem to work for me on the same version of firefox. Are you getting any specific error messages?

Comment: Actually a specific country map is hosted on one of our server. and when i update my browser it stop working. it was working on previous version.

Comment: What errors do you see in the developer tools in Firefox? Have others using the same map reported the same problem? What API is the map (JavaScript, Silverlight, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, the next day's FF update fix the problem for me, have you tried upgrading ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by downgrading Firefox to previous version, then everything worked. Probably Javascript problem. You can downgrade or wait for an updated version fixing this issue.